# Gesture recognizer stopped working in iOS 4.3

Tags: cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, swipe, ios4

My gesture recognition code worked fine in iOS 4.2 but in iOS 4.3 it does not work. I can't find any documented changes in gesture recognizers from iOS 4.2 to 4.3 but I have confirmed both on an iPad and in the simulator that my code is no longer working.

This is what I am doing:

In my view controller's ViewDidLoad method, I put:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUpGesture = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedScreenLeft:)] autorelease];
swipeUpGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
swipeUpGesture.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft);
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpGesture];
```

In iOS 4.2 this works as expected but in iOS 4.3 swipedScreenLeft is never called even when I swipe with two fingers. Everything compiles and runs though with no errors or warnings.

Is there anything that might prevent this gesture recognizer from working in iOS 4.3 even though it works fine in iOS 4.2?

Also I have noticed that under iOS 4.2 if I touched the screen with two fingers but did not make the correct gesture, nothing would happen but in iOS 4.3 if I touch the screen with two fingers, it acts as if I am only touching with one finger. It is as if iOS 4.3 does not recognize multi touch events in my app.

Another note: my tapGestureRecognizer works fine in iOS 4.3 it's just the swipeGestureRecognizer that does not.

Comment: Same problem here, stopped working in iOS 4.3, was fine prior.

Comment: I'm glad to find somebody with the same problem as me. Please let me know if you figure it out and I'll do the same. Does your code use the gesture recognizer on a scroll view as well?

Comment: My gesture recognizer is on the apps main window so it's available across the entire app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with UIScrollView only, I also made a rage about it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqx3d.png

[UPDATE 1] Here the solution:

The situation: A UIViewController's view has a UIScrollView as subview (the scroll view paging is disabled).

Code I use to attach the gesture the the UIView:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedScreenLeft:)];
[swipeLeftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2.0f];
swipeLeftRecognizer.delegate = self;
[swipeLeftRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRecognizer];

[swipeLeftRecognizer release];
```

To be iOS 4.3 enabled, I only had to add the UIViewController as a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Then, I used the following delegate method to intercept and allow the simultaneous recognition of the scrollView's panGesture with the view's swipe one. Here the code:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]] && [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;

}
```

[UPDATE 2]

To disable the UIScrollView panning with two fingers, I THINK that you have to make your scrollview, a custom subclass of the UISCrollView class and alter some behavior of the panGesture detector, BUT I didn't tried to do that. 
Instead I choosed a lazier solution, basically I enable/disable the scrollView scroll functionlity based on the current state of the UISwipeGestureRecognizer.
Moreover, in order to prevent double touch movement in the other direction too, I attached another recognizer just for that purpose.

You have to create two properties for your swipe detectors.

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightRecognizer;
@property (nonatomic,assign) UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftRecognizer;
```

Then I coded like this:

```
[self setSwipeRightRecognizer:[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:nil action:nil]];
[swipeRightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2.0f];
swipeRightRecognizer.delegate = self;
[swipeRightRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"swipeRightRecognizer.state" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightRecognizer];
[swipeRightRecognizer release];

[self setSwipeLeftRecognizer:[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedScreenLeft:)]];
[swipeLeftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2.0f];
swipeLeftRecognizer.delegate = self;
[swipeLeftRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"swipeLeftRecognizer.state" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRecognizer];
[swipeLeftRecognizer release];
```

then add this method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (self.swipeRightRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {
        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        return;
    }

    if ([self.swipeRightRecognizer numberOfTouches] != 2.0f) {
        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;   
    }
    else{
        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;   
    }
}
```

And update the existing method I posted in the previous "[UPDATE]":

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]] && [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        if ([gestureRecognizer numberOfTouches] != 2.0f) {
            self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;   
        }
        else{
            self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;   
        }

        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Finally, remove the observers in the dealloc:

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"swipeRightRecognizer.state"];
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"swipeLeftRecognizer.state"];
```

I bet there is a cleaner solution, but it works.. .

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Okay so I added UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to my main view controller's header file:

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {

And then defined the delegate method like you did:


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
...
}

but the delegate method never seems to get called. I even put an NSLog into it and I never see that pop up in the console, so something is weird. Any idea what might prevent the delegate from being called?

Comment: I think I just needed to add the delegate to each of my gestures (for example [swipeDownGesture setDelegate:self]; etc...). 

while that seems to work, the behavior is still different than 4.2. In iOS 4.2 when I touched my scrollView with two fingers (for example when Iw as beginning a gesture) it would not scroll (it would only scroll with one finger). Now it seems to scroll while I am attempting the gesture with two fingers. Any idea why that behavior would be different?

Comment: Awesome, I'll take a look at this tonight and see how it goes!

Comment: I think the addition of the if statement inside shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer was enough to make it behave like the iOS 4.2 app again (and hence everything once again works). Thanks so much! I'd like to reward you with a promo code for my app if you're interested. I'm not sure if you can PM me on here, but if not hit me up via my website and I'll give you a code for a free download!

Comment: Actually maybe it's not solved. It seems like my scrollView can no sometimes lockup now if a two finger gesture is attempted that is not recognized. Hmm maybe I need to implement the complicated solution. I still can't figure out why this is different in 4.3. It wasn't documented by Apple very well.

Comment: @Jackson Yep, I think you should try the complex one. If it goes well, I would appreciate the redeem, keep me updated ^^

Comment: Hmm still did not get it...
The reason I want to make it not scroll while two fingers are touched to the UIScrollView is because the two finger swipe gesture is for a "scroll to page" method and my scrollView holds many pages each with an image. Basically, swipe left and swipe right will skip to the first and last image in the scrollView. If the two finger gesture is triggered while an image has been partially scrolled to one side, then my scrollToPage method does not work (it needs to start from the zero position for each page for it to scroll to the first or last page correctly).

Comment: Maybe the simplest solution would be to fix my scrollToPage function so it takes into account the starting offset rather than messing with the way iOS handles the scrollView to begin with....

Comment: by the way, if I remove the "animate" property of my scrollToPage method it works fine even though the gesture might have been triggered while it was partially scrolled. Not the best solution because I liked animating the transition triggered by the gesture but I might leave it like that to avoid overcomplicating my code. Thanks again! Contact me for the promo code! :)

Comment: that's weird, hope you'll find a definitive solution :s, ok I'll contact you ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you use UIImageView and you want to handle double taps on it, you should enable User Interaction. I wasted a lot of time to find out this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my code can help you with your problem.
i've tested the code on an iPad with iOS 4.3
And it works perfectly

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oSwipeLeft = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mPreviousPage:) ] autorelease];
oSwipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
oSwipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:oSwipeLeft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oSwipeRight = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mNextPage:) ] autorelease];
oSwipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
oSwipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:oSwipeRight];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oSwipeUp = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mPreviousPage:) ] autorelease];
oSwipeUp.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
oSwipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:oSwipeUp];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems that your code is identical to mine except you put self.view where I put scrollview (the name of my view). I tried it your way and the app still doesn't seem to recognize multiple touches. That makes me think there is something somewhere else in my code that is disabling multi touches in iOS 4.3 but not in 4.2. Out of curiosity, is your view a scroll view or a different type of view?

Comment: i See that the problem is solved. 
in reply to your question, i'm using a table view.